# Unable to delete Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to delete a subsite in my site collection, but I get an error that says "Can not reach the Messages.xml file!"

A few days ago I was able to delete a site, but now it seems to be impossible to delete any sub sites.

If I use the stsadm deleteweb with force parameter I'm able to delete, but I would like to be able to delete sites via the interface.

I'm thinking that the error might be coming from some feature because the error message is in english and all other Sharepoint msg is in danish(Running a danish version of Sharepoint 2007)

Any suggestions?

Regards
Birger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was happening because the MSITDeleteFeature had been installed some time ago and after moving the site to a new server som of the feature was not correctly installed on the new server.
The missing Messages.xml was a part of the feature and should have been placed in this folder
C:\program files\common files\Microsoft shared\web server extensions\12\template\layouts\1030

After copying the file to the folder the problem was solved.

/Birger